# adding to a list with special limit

Tags: java, string, arraylist, substring

Consider the following list of words:
but my list would contain 100,000 words

```
small 
donations 
($1 
to 
$5,000) 
are 
particularly 
important 
to 
maintaining 
tax 
exempt
```

Currently this code below **gets the first 100 characters worth of words** and puts it in another list *(called SecondarrayList)*. I want it to add every 100 characters until the end of the list *(and each element in the list is a word)*.

So we only want **100 characters worth of words** and that's it at each iteration until the last word. Must **not** exceed the *100 char limit*.

```
int totalSize = 0;
for (String eachString : list) {
    totalSize += eachString.length();
    if (totalSize >= 100)
        break;
    else
      SecondarrayList.add(eachString);
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question? Because you accidentally...

Comment: @elliot yes,so how do i add every 100 chacters worth of words to a list named secondaryarraylist?

Comment: In what way does your current code **not** do that?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch current code only gets first 100 chracters worth of words and it stops. I want it to iterate over untill end and put every 100 characters worth in seperate element in a list

Comment: It is unclear what you expect result to be. 1) Do you want exactly 100 characters, or do you want as many words as possible, not exceeding 100 characters? 2) When you have 100 chars or words totalling <= 100 chars, how do you want that added to `SecondarrayList`? 2a) As a (sub-)list? 2b) Merged to a single string? 2c) Merged with space-separators? 2d) Something else? --- Please edit question to show expected output, e.g. if limit is 20 (since 100 wouldn't split sample input).

Comment: @Andreas How do i keep iterating through the list without stopping untill the end of the list. There are still more words to be processed. However, every 100 characters worth of words there should be some kind of counter to keep track. every 100 characters I need to know it reached that

Comment: @dedpo Simple enough: Don't `break` the loop and it will continue until the end. When you reach your limit (100 chars), do what you need to do, then reset the counter to 0, and continue looping.

Comment: @Andreas i did take the break off, and put counter. It still puts the same out put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you can check if the individual `String`(s) are less than 100 characters in length (if so add them directly to the second arraylist). Otherwise, add the first 100 characters to the second arraylist. Also, by Java variable naming convention, the second arraylist should be named `secondArrayList`. Something like,

```
List<String> secondArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String eachString : list) {
    if (eachString.length() < 100) { // <-- is it 100 or fewer chars?
        secondArrayList.add(eachString);
    } else { // <-- otherwise, take the first 100 chars.
        secondArrayList.add(eachString.substring(0, 100));
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to take each 100 characters of one input into multiple "words" then your else should look something like

```
} else {
    // Iterate the word, shrinking by 100 characters...
    while (eachString.length() > 100) {
        secondArrayList.add(eachString.substring(0, 100));
        eachString = eachString.substring(100);
    }
    // Check if there is anything left...
    if (!eachString.isEmpty()) {
        secondArrayList.add(eachString);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, so now each element  secondArraylist does it contain 100 characters or less worth of words? because that is what's required

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
int length = 0;

for (String str : list){
    int totalLength = str.length();
    int startPos = 0;
    //if you have strings longer than 100 characters
    //also handles left overs from previous iterations
    while (length+totalLength>=100){
           int actualLength = Math.min(100,totalLength)
           strBuilder.append(str.substring(startPos,startPos+actualLength));
           secondArrayList.add(strBuilder.build());
           strBuilder.setLength(0);
           startPos += actualLength;
           totalLength -= actualLength;
           length = 0;
    }
    //we know it is safe to add remainder as it is
    // or if the new word skipped the while loop we add it completly
    strBuilder.append(str.substring(startPos,startPos+totalLength))
    length += totalLength;
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I have not compiled the code and tested it! It does not cover all corner cases probably.